# What MySQL Datatype to use for two capital letters

Tags: mysql

I'd like to store the area part of a UK postcode (zip code) in db column. The potential size of the db will run into millions of records so I'm keen for the column to take up as little space as possible.

What I want to store will be one two capital letters - "CO" , "SE" or "B"  ect

What's the best datatype to use for this column? TEXT?

Many thanks

Comment: Use a `CHAR(2)` - it's of fixed length so faster than `VARCHAR` because the engine knows how far to skip ahead over it if needbe. Don't use a `TEXT` field as they're used for storing long strings

Comment: No problem. I probably should've put it as an answer in the first place but it's one now.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CHAR(2)` - it's of fixed length so faster than `VARCHAR` because the engine knows how far to skip ahead over it if needbe. Don't use a `TEXT` field as they're used for storing long strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHAR(2) or TINYTEXT for description but you can checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html